# Missing matrix fields

Tags: control-panel

This is a head scratcher. We have a site we are about to launch that was ready to go when suddenly at some point in the day yesterday a bunch of Matrix fields within a group went missing. Just gone. Of course this broke the site and our templates started erroring out. Our first instinct was that they were manually deleted but the client is saying that they didn't touch the fields area. We also talked to the web host / Arcustech and they said that everything looked fine on their end. We had to restore the database which was a bummer.

So my question is, could this have been due to a recent bug? Is there a way we can see what fields get deleted via the logs? It's really bothering us that we can't pinpoint exactly what happened here.

I should mention we were on 2.2.2592 when this happened. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I just got word that one of our developers had a request to change a caption to a rich text field. Not concerned about the data loss for that particular field he made the switch. At that point he claims his connection hung along with the post. Eventually it posted. He didn't notice it at the time but he's saying that everything past the field he was editing, including other fields in other block types below the one he was on got deleted. The block types themselves stayed. Very strange scenario but I think we have a bit of closure on this one. We'll send a ticket your way for sure. Thanks.

Comment: Logs were rolled back with the full restore unfortunately so I'm not sure a ticket would do any good. Obviously if there are connection issues there is not much we can do to avoid such a thing. Again thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in Craft will automatically delete Matrix fields, and there haven’t been any DB migrations that would have deleted an entire Matrix field. (There was a recent migration that deleted some orphaned Matrix block rows in the DB, but that would only have affected the data, not the fields themselves, and wouldn’t have made any noticeable change in the Control Panel.) Someone must have gone in and deleted the field, or changed its name/field type.

If it happened recently enough, there might still be some evidence of it in your logs. We can take a look - just send in a ticket from your Dashboard and they will be included automatically.